# std::format with custom types

Tags: c++, c++20, fmt

The C++20 format library supports custom types. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter) gives an example with a box type:

```
// A wrapper for type T
template<class T>
struct Box 
{
    T value;
};
 
// The wrapper Box<T> can be formatted using the format specification of the wrapped value
template<class T, class CharT>
struct std::formatter<Box<T>, CharT> : std::formatter<T, CharT> 
{
    // parse() is inherited from the base class
 
    // Define format() by calling the base class implementation with the wrapped value
    template<class FormatContext>
    auto format(Box<T> t, FormatContext& fc) const 
    {
        return std::formatter<T, CharT>::format(t.value, fc);
    }
};
 
int main() 
{
    Box<int> v = { 42 };
    std::cout << std::format("{:#x}", v);
}
```

This example does not work though with a type not supported by 'basic_format_arg'. For example this does not compile (using a long instead of a int):

```
int main() 
{
    Box<long> v = { 42 };
    std::cout << std::format("{}", v);
}
```

Anyone to rescue? Hacks are using int when long is specified but that is not a general solution. Alternatively a full blown formatter can be written though that gave also compilation errors when using a basic_string to cache the placeholder.

Comment: [It does too compile.](https://godbolt.org/z/sGMrMK5as)

Comment: @Barry: not with long: C:/data/msvc/14.33.31424-Pre/include\format(2900): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::basic_format_arg<_Context>'

Comment: You should file a bug report, that's an MSVC bug.

Comment: I wonder why `t` is passed by value in the example...

Comment: @Barry: not sure if it's a bug since basic_format_arg doesn't support all types https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/basic_format_arg

Comment: @gast128 Not relevant? `formatter<long, char>` exists and has to work when passed a `long`, which is what you're doing. You're not trying to construct a `basic_format_arg` (and `basic_format_arg` (a) does support all types and (b) is constructible from `long` anyway, it'd hold a `long long int`).

Comment: I created a pull request: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/2768
So it will be fixed soon, probably in VS 2022 17.4 Preview 1 or Preview 2

Answer (score 1):

The only issue in this example is a missing `<iostream>` include.

```cpp
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

// A wrapper for type T
template<class T>
struct Box 
{
    T value;
};
 
// The wrapper Box<T> can be formatted using the format specification of the wrapped value
template<class T, class CharT>
struct std::formatter<Box<T>, CharT> : std::formatter<T, CharT> 
{
    // parse() is inherited from the base class
 
    // Define format() by calling the base class implementation with the wrapped value
    template<class FormatContext>
    auto format(Box<T> t, FormatContext& fc) const 
    {
        return std::formatter<T, CharT>::format(t.value, fc);
    }
};
 
int main() 
{
    Box<int> v = { 42 };
    std::cout << std::format("{:#x}", v);
}
```

It compiles with libc++/clang (https://godbolt.org/z/sr14Mb9c6) and the error is likely a bug in Microsoft STL and/or MSVC.